# Tutorial for tile based side scroller game-play?

Tags: c++, c

Does anyone know a good resource or some pointers which could help me make a side scrolling tile based (descreet movement for character) with box pushing and moving platforms etc. I'm focused right now C/C++ console development (tho after this project I may stop and do stuff a little more graphical, still C/C++). Something bit like [Super Serib Bros](http://www.foon.co.uk/farcade/ssb/). I've taken a look at the code of SSB and I have some idea of how it works, tho the variable names aren't particularly helpful.

It occurs to me someone somewhere must have thought about his problem before. So before I go re-inventing the wheel, any clues?

Answer (score 2):

You'd probably be best signing in one of the better known game development groups, for example [GameDev](http://www.gamedev.net/) or [DevMaster](http://www.devmaster.net/) as well as checking out the stuff [Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/express/gamedevelopment/) pushes.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how many resources you will find for making games, as most open source games develop their own tools and commercial games keep their tools private.

I think that the best strategy is to start from scratch, using existing low-level libraries.

For C++, I recommend using [Box2d](http://box2d.org) for physics and [HGE](http://hge.relishgames.com/) for graphics.  I have also heard that python's pygame library is good, but have not tried it myself.

Comment: You don't need physics for a game like that. That'll over-complicate it.

Answer (score 0):

I use a an editor/engine called [RPG Maker](http://www.play-asia.com/paOS-13-71-7s-49-en-15-rpg%20maker%20vx-70-2b0a.html) for fun in my spare time.  You can download the demo for free.  It is a tile based rpg engine and is pretty basic, but the engine is written in ruby and can be browsed very easily.